# HTML page to PDF with automatic height

Tags: c#, html, pdf, converters

I have an HTML page that I need to convert to PDF with C#, and I can't find how to make sure my PDF have exactly a width of 80mm and an automatic height (depending of content of the page). The HTML file is a receipt.

I have tried many libraries, but can't find the optimal solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Why can you not output to PDF from an HTML client such as a web browser?

Comment: It will be generated from a desktop application and send by email directly in PDF.

Comment: Have you tried itext 7/ pdfHTML? There are scaling options that will get to the 80mm you are looking for.

Comment: Is there a free solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try frindly print as pdf and add spacific print style like this

```
/* override styles when printing */
@media print {

  body {
    /* body styles when printing */
  }

}
```

You can take a look at [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/css-printer-friendly-pages/)

Comment: The problem is that my <html> is already to a size of 80mm, so the @media print will not change anything.